# Wpf binding to Foreground with GridViewColumn

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listview, gridviewcolumn

I'm doing :

```
<ListView Margin="34,42,42,25" Name="listView1">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Width="550" Header="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=MyValue}"/>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
  <ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
    </Style>
  </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

and this is working, I can see my items in Green.

Now, I want to use a binding value with this, so I have a property :

```
private Color _theColor;

public System.Windows.Media.Color TheColor
{
    get { return _theColor; }
    set
    {
        if (_theColor != value)
        {
            _theColor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TheColor");
        }
    }
}
```

but If I use this binding :

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=TheColor}"/>
```

It's not working...

How can I correct that ?

Of course, I'm setting the TheColor to `Colors.Green` ...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, you can't bind to a `Color`.  The `Foreground` need to be set to a `Brush`.  So I would set the value to a `SolidColorBrush` and bind the `Brush`'s color property to your `TheColor` `DependencyProperty`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=TheColor}" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In my example I just bound the property `TheColor` to a `DependencyProperty`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TheColorProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("TheColor", typeof(System.Windows.Media.Color), typeof(YourWindow));

public System.Windows.Media.Color TheColor
{
    get { return (System.Windows.Media.Color)GetValue(TheColorProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TheColorProperty, value); }
}
```

After that, you can bind to the `TheColor` `DependencyProperty`.  In my case, I just gave the main Window/UserControl/Page an x:Name and bound to that:

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=TheColor, ElementName=yourWindowVar}" />
```